# Possible to add page numbers and footer to docx WITHOUT specifying template?

Tags: pandoc

I've only startd looking into pandoc a few hours ago so there's still lots I don't know.  I know that if I modify a generated docx and add footer and page numbers, then I can use that as a template, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use pandox without a template and generate a footer and page numbers?

I was thinking this would be possible

```
pandoc <args> --page_numbers --footer="Created by John Smith"
```

Or is that only doable with a template?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is currently no default template for the docx format (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20147516/2535792), [2](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pandoc-discuss/_KyoGN1Zf5g/rzq367675ecJ), [3](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/issues/20)) so you cannot pass a footer file by command line.

You can use the `reference-docx` option to provide a footer but cannot override the `footer` variable:

```
pandoc -f markdown --reference-docx=template.docx -t docx input.md -o output.docx
```

Edit: Adding (from Word) page numbers on the template does work.

Comment: So I can use a specific footer, but there's no way to make it a variable basically? Do you also know the answer about page numbers?

Comment: Exactly! Adding the page number in the footer does work. Count is incremented if needed.

Comment: Page numbers are treated the same as footer/header?

Comment: What do you mean? Inserting page numbers into the template from Word will add page numbers on the output document.

Comment: I mean: there is no way to specify a parameter to pandoc saying `--page_nums=true/false`, right? Page numbers will only exist if using a template document that has page numbers?

Comment: Correct. Pandoc does not provide an option to toggle page numbering (regardless of the output format).